# Reduce the equation $x^2y''\:+\:2xy'\:-\:5y\:=\:0$ with $x=e^z$

Tags: calculus

reduce the equation

> $(1)\:\:\:x^2\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)+2x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-5y=0$

to a differential equation with constant coefficients in $\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}$, $\frac{dy}{dz}$, and $y$ by the change of variable $x=e^z$.

first i try to find $\frac{dy}{dz}$ using chain rule

$\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dz}=e^z\frac{dy}{dx}$

> $(a)\:\:\:\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz}$

and then find for $\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}$, since $\frac{d}{dz}=e^z\frac{d}{dx}$ thus

> $(b)\:\:\:\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^{-2z}\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}$

substitute $x$, $(a)$ and $(b)$ into $(1)$ i get

> $\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+2\frac{dy}{dz}-5y=0$

but the answer in my book is

$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+\frac{dy}{dz}-5y=0$

my answer still has the factor 2 on the LHS. Is there an error in my calculation? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that $$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}=\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^z\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{de^z}{dz}\frac{dy}{dx}+e^z\frac{d}{dz}\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Comment: whoa i didn't realize that! thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have an equation of the form $a_n x^n y^{(n)}+\cdots+a_1 x y'+a_0 y=0$

Now let $x=e^z$. Let ${\rm d}=d/dx$ and ${\rm D}=d/dz$. We want to express ${\rm d }y$ in terms of ${\rm D}y$. Now, by the chain rule $${\rm d}y=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}={\rm D}y \frac 1 x$$

So that $x {\rm d}y={\rm D}y$. Then ${\rm d}y=x^{-1}{\rm D}y$ so, since $x{\rm d}={\rm D}$, $$\begin{align}{\rm d}^2y&={\rm d}(x^{-1}{\rm D}y)\\&=x^{-1}{\rm D}(e^{-z}{\rm D}y)\\&=x^{-1}(-e^{-z}{\rm D}y+e^{-z}{\rm D}^2y)\\&=e^{-2z}({\rm D}({\rm D}-1)y)\end{align}$$

Hence $x^2{\rm d}^2={\rm D}({\rm D}-1)$. Continuing, you can show that $x^n{\rm d}^n={\rm D}({\rm D}-1)\cdots ({\rm D}-n+1)$.